# Controller Services Stuck in Enabling Stage

Tags: apache-nifi

I am creating a controller service of type "DBCPConnectionPool". However the service is not going to enabled state but stuck in enabling stage. Do let me know how to debug the same. I am connecting to Jira to get the ticket details. Please help me debug.

Adding screenshot below
[image: Controller Service Configuration]

[image: Enabling stage of controller]

Comment: Please provide the bulletin error (red file icon on the left of the DBCP name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb with this controller service, it gets stuck when it's unable to open a connection to the remote data source. Try manually creating a JDBC from that machine to your database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to connect manually to teradata using same jdbc URL & driver. But form NiFi. it gets stuck in enabling state. And when I try to disable it, it gets stuck in disabling state. The 'Delete' option is also missing for these enabling/disabling connections.